# as3 for loop 'stairs'

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop

I have a very simple question. I'm trying to make a set of ascending stairs by looping over and placing individual sections on the stage.

```
for(i= 0; i<20 ;i++){
  var platform:Platform=new Platform("floor" +i,{width:20,height:20,x:20*i,y:i*20});
  trace("added")
  add(platform);
}
```

this creates the aforementioned 'stair' pattern but in a descending fashion can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm sure it's very simple

Comment: The "design-patterns" tag does not belong to this question. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern

Answer (score 1):

What you want can be achieved by reducing the y-position as x-position increases. For instance, instead of setting y to `i * 20`, you can set it to `400 - i * 20`.